Blazor, html tag with empty attribute b-k6xksvc12j=""
Scenario: Blazor, .NET 6.0, and Razor Custom Component Project (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web 6.0.29)
The html rendering stage my html project adds the b-k6xksvc12j="" attribute to each element.
Screenshot of html code
On the page I add a Razor custom component (UISupportRazor.Menu) created with another project.
The custom component is not rendered with the b-k6xksvc12j attribute and therefore is displayed with a different graphic style (there are style rules that blazor assigns to tags with the b-k6xksvc12j attributes)
    @* Component to add for dynamic rendering of AI-generated content *@
    @{
        var Features = UISupportGeneric.Util.GetAllClassInfoInNamespace("Cloud.Features", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
    <UISupportRazor.Menu ClassesInfo="@Features"></UISupportRazor.Menu>


How do I make custom elements also have the b-k6xksvc12j attribute?

The attribute you are referring to is generated when you add an isolated .css to your project. For example, for UISupportRazor.Menu.razor add UISupportRazor.Menu.razor.css when the compiler sees that your using isolated css files it will add the attribute to all html elements in the UISupportRazor.Menu.razor markup. The ::deep selector could also be used to target the subcomponents if they don't have isolation.

How do you extend isolated css even at tags generated by costom controls in external projects?
